# KStream - KTable Join - Patterns to Update Already Enriched Records when Reference Data on KTable Side Gets an Update

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

Question on the `KStream - KTable` joins. Usually this kind of join is used for data enrichment purposes where the KTable provides reference data.

So the question is, when the KTable record gets an update, how do we go about updating the older records that we already processed, enriched and probably stored in some data store?

Are there any patterns that we can follow?

(Please assume `KTable - KTable` wouldn’t be an option as `KStream` side would emit large volume of changes)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think of such joins as enriching the stream of data.  In that view, records which have come through the join before an update to the `KTable` are "correct" at the time.

I can see two options to consider:

First, as a Kafka Streams option, would a `KStream-KStream` join work?
It sounds like that's the processing semantics that you'd like.
(Incidentally, I really like the docs for showing clear examples of when records are and are not emitted: https://kafka.apache.org/31/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-kstream-join)

Second, since it sounds like you may be persisting the streaming data, in this case, it may make sense to do query time enrichment.  Creating a view/join over the two tables in the data store may provide a sane alternative to reprocessing data in the database.

Comment: I agree with the options that you have suggested about doing query time enrichment. 

I think we need to solve this in a case-by-case basis. One option is query time enrichment, others are:

Comment: -  using a ktable-ktable join instead but with less data retention to reduce the volume overload.

Comment: - Using a separate processor that will listen to the topic treated as the reference table and perform bulk updates on already enriched data.